# Set response headers

Tags: hapi.js

I need to set some response headers within server.onPreHandler ext method.
There are 2 scenarios, where I need this happen when user sends an API request to my route end point.
1) In success scenario, I need to set headers and let process continue further down life cycle
2) In error scenario (where user has not provided a required field), I need to set headers and return immediately to user with appropriate error info.

In both of these scenarios, I would like to set response headers.
In the 2nd scenario above, I am able to invoke reply.response('error') and then set response header to it using response.header('x', 'value').  However, in the 1st scenario, where before calling reply.continue() I am trying to set header using request.response.header('x', 'value), I get response null error.

Please help

Thanks
Ramesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm able to change response headers like this. Have you tried this way?

```
// at your onPreResponse ext body
const response = request.response;
if (request.response.isBoom) {
    response.output.headers['x'] = 'value';
} else {
    response.header('x', 'value');
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response

Since request.response is null we get "cannot call isBoom on null"
Cannot read property 'isBoom' of null

Comment: Hmm, of course there is no response at onPreHandler level. You need to do your work in onPostHandler or onPreResponse ext point.

Comment: Thank you so much.  We added logic on onPreProcess ext point to get the response headers set

Comment: Any idea how to delete the key and value pair entirely?